# Installing trust anchors or certificates from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a key management application for the universal windows platform and would like to install CA certificates and trust anchors that can be used by system apps and 3rd-party apps. I have tried using a combination of CertificateStores.GetStoreByName and CertificateStore.Add as well as a call accessed via P/Invoke to CertAddEncodedCertificateToStore. Unfortunately, in both cases the calls succeed but the certificates are not visible using MMC and they do not appear to be used by other applications.

Is there a means of installing certificates such that they are usable system-wide (including outside the app container)? Is there any means of viewing what certificates have been installed within an app container?

Comment: Right now, there isn't a way to do that. You can't make system wide changes from a UWP app. You'd need to use a traditional Win32 application to manage certificates.

Comment: Thanks. That was my guess but was hoping there was something similar to the way changes can be made to the system-wide MY store and would still like a way to view the certs and TAs installed for an app.

Comment: I wouldn't expect this to change either. It's rare that a trusted consumer app should legitimately modify for the entire system the certificate store. If it's an enterprise app, I'd either suggest just installing the certificates via powershell or a win32 app.

Comment: I don't follow your point. Ought UWP not be used for an "enterprise" app? Other platforms support this, albeit with user intervention (which is fine). Rare though it may be, this is an instance where it is necessary and appropriate.

Comment: Regardless of it being appropriate in your scenario, it doesn't work in a UWP app as they are sandboxed to prevent this type of system-level modification. UWP apps aren't for every scenario yet as you've seen

Comment: @Carl  do u find any solution ?

Answer (score 6):

By default no. Please check [introduction to certificates article.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt270185.aspx)

> **Shared certificate stores**
>
> UWP apps use the new isolationist application model introduced in Windows 8. In this model, apps run in
>   low-level operating system construct, called an app container, that
>   prohibits the app from accessing resources or files outside of itself
>   unless explicitly permitted to do so. The following sections describe
>   the implications this has on public key infrastructure (PKI).
>
> **Certificate storage per app container**
>
> Certificates that are intended for use in a specific app container are stored in per user,
>   per app container locations. An app running in an app container has
>   write access to only its own certificate storage. If the application
>   adds certificates to any of its stores, these certificates cannot be
>   read by other apps. If an app is uninstalled, any certificates
>   specific to it are also removed. An app also has read access to local
>   machine certificate stores other than the MY and REQUEST store.

Anyway, you can add a capability to your application in Package.appxmanifest. The **sharedUserCertificates** capability grants an app container read access to the certificates and keys contained in the user MY store and the Smart Card Trusted Roots store.

```
  <Capabilities>
    <uap:Capability Name="sharedUserCertificates" />
  </Capabilities>
```

I just added it for testing purpose (UWP application) and the following code works fine. Certificate is added on user MY store.

```
string pfxCertificate = null;
string pfxPassword = "";    

FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".pfx");
filePicker.CommitButtonText = "Open";

try
{
    StorageFile file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        // file was picked and is available for read
        // try to read the file content
        IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
        using (DataReader dataReader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
            dataReader.ReadBytes(bytes);
            // convert to Base64 for using with ImportPfx
            pfxCertificate = System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        }

        await CertificateEnrollmentManager.UserCertificateEnrollmentManager.ImportPfxDataAsync(
            pfxCertificate,
            pfxPassword,
            ExportOption.NotExportable,
            KeyProtectionLevel.NoConsent,
            InstallOptions.None,
            "Test");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

A sample is available on 8.1 if it helps. [Cryptography and Certificate sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Cryptography-and-3305467b)

Comment: This is not the goal. I can also successfully add a P12 file (using the same mechanism). I would like to add a certificate to the CA or Root store that is used system wide. I would also like to be able to see which certificates are installed in the certificate store for a give app container. Here's a snip illustrative of what i have tried:            byte[] binaryCert = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Cert);
            Certificate cert = new Certificate(binaryCert.AsBuffer());
            CertificateStores.TrustedRootCertificationAuthorities.Add(cert);